# Login redirect rendering twice

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

I'm using reach router for my routes. I was able to protect the dashboard and expose the login page and redirect if the user is not logged in but now if I enter a url it will do a quick redirecto to login and then to home instead of the page actually entered.

I noticed because of the useEffect to fetch the user the component renders twice: 1 without user (redirects to login) the other one with user and redirects to home.

Routes file

```
const AdminRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <MainLayout path="/admin">
        <HomePage path="/" />
        <CarTransfer path="/cartransfers">
          <CarTranserList path="/list" />
          <CarTransferCreate path="/new" />
        </CarTransfer>
        <User path="/users">
          <UserList path="/list" />
          <UserCreate path="/new" />
        </User>
      </MainLayout>
      <LoginPage path="/login" />
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Layout file

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Redirect, useNavigate } from "@reach/router";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import SiderMenu from "./SiderMenu";
import LayoutBanner from "./LayoutBanner";

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  userSelector,
  fetchUserBytoken,
  clearState,
} from "../../features/authSlice";

const { Content } = Layout;

const MainLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const user = useSelector(userSelector);
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isFetching, isError } = useSelector(userSelector);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      fetchUserBytoken({
        token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
        id: localStorage.getItem("id"),
      })
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      dispatch(clearState());
      navigate("/login");
    }
  }, [isError]);

  const handleOnCollapse = () => {
    setCollapsed((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  if (isFetching) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }

  if (user.id === "") {
    return <Redirect noThrow to="/login" />;
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SiderMenu collapsed={collapsed} handleOnCollapse={handleOnCollapse} />
      <Layout>
        <LayoutBanner
          collapsed={collapsed}
          handleOnCollapse={handleOnCollapse}
        />
        <Content>{children}</Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default MainLayout;
```

**The second question would be how to get to the same page you were before the login redirect after login.**

Thanks

Comment: To answer your second question - to go back to a previews page you use `history`. `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";` Import it. create a variable to store ur history `let history = useHistory();` and then inside whatever event you wish execute `history.goBack()`. that will bring you 1 page back.

Comment: thanks, this is reach router, not react router but I will search for the equivalent